# Vector spaces, subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra

Examine that $W$ is a subspace of the vector space $M_{3x3}$

$W=({A:det(A) \ge} 0)$

I have two conditions:

1) $ \vec u + \vec v \in W $

2) $ \alpha \cdot \vec u \in W $

$ B,C \in W $

$det(B) + det(C) \ge 0 $

I don't know any properties of determine of matrix which could help with these.

Comment: I don't understand your attempt: you've just written down four inequalities, with no clue as to what you're doing with them. Please explain further.

Comment: @ChrisEagle - do you think that the claim is true ? how about $diag(-2,-8,1)+diag(3,3,3)$ as a counterexample ?

Comment: @ChrisEagle - or take something in $W$ and the scalar as $-1$ then $det$ changes signs

Comment: Yeah, let $A\in W$. Then $(-A)\in W$. But $A+(-A)=0\notin W$, contradiction, therefore etc. etc. etc.

Comment: @Belgi: Why are you telling me this? Of course I can solve this problem. Post an answer if you want to.

Comment: It was wrong what i've wrote. I have no idea how start with it.

Comment: @ChrisEagle I trust that you know the answer, but because you asked the OP about his effort that threw me off to think that he is trying to prove something that correct...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This claim is not true:**

First, note that $A=diag(-2,-8,1),B=diag(3,3,3)\in W$ but $A+B\not\in W$.

Moreover, if $A\in W$ then $|-A|=(-1)^{3}|A|\leq0$ and so $-A\in W$
iff $|A|=0$ but there are matrices in $W$ with non-zero determinant

Answer (score 2):

$W=\{A\colon \det A\geq 0\}$ is not a subspace of the vector space $M_{3\times3}$ (I assume it is over the reals). Take for example 
$$
I=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0& 0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Obviously $\det I=1$ and $I\in W$. Now take $(-1)I$ and observe that $\det (-1)I=(-1)^3\det I$.